# Issues with movement in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have my image moving correctly when I put in the inputs, but since I need the image to quit moving when I let go of the key, I naturally used pygame.KEYUP to make all movement stop. However, this leads to choppy gameplay because if you even hit a button a fraction of a second before you let off the one you were holding, your character stops all together, and sometimes it feels like it happens even when I do let off the button in time, though I suppose that could just be on me. Is there another way I can code the movement so that this isn't a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use:

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == ord('d'):
        Right = True
if event.type == KEYUP:
    if event.key == ord('d'):
        Right = False
```

(Somewhere else in the code...)

`if Right == True:`

```
PlayerX += 10
```

(Then)

`screen.blit(PlayerImage,(PlayerX,PlayerY))`

Answer (score 0):

Just stop using events for movement.

Simply use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` to check which keys are pressed, then alter the position of your game object accordingly.

Here's a minimal example of a moving monkey:

```
import base64, pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *

def magnitude(v):
    return math.sqrt(sum(v[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(v))))

def add(u, v):
    return [ u[i]+v[i] for i in range(len(u)) ]

def normalize(v):
    vmag = magnitude(v)
    return [ v[i]/vmag  for i in range(len(v)) ]

pygame.init()
size = width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
img = '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'

player = pygame.image.fromstring(base64.b64decode(img, 'UTF-8'), (36, 56), 'RGBA')
player_rect = player.get_rect()

# define which keys move the monkey in which direction
move_map = {pygame.K_w: ( 0, -1),
            pygame.K_s: ( 0,  1),
            pygame.K_a: (-1,  0),
            pygame.K_d: ( 1,  0)}

def main():
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while running:
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("darkgreen"))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        # get all pressed keys
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # get all directions the monkey should move
        move = [move_map[key] for key in move_map if pressed[key]]

        # add all directions together to get the final direction
        reduced = reduce(add, move, (0, 0))
        if reduced != (0, 0):
            # normalize the target direction and apply a speed
            move_vector = [c * 5 for c in normalize(reduced)]

            # move the monkey...
            player_rect.move_ip(*move_vector)

            # ...but keep it inside the screen
            player_rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())

        screen.blit(player, player_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: I must admit I'm having trouble following this code. It's mainly because I haven't been able to completely familiarize myself with pygame. When I read the documentation for clamp_ip and things like that I have trouble following what it's actually doing. I have switched to pygame.key.get_pressed(), but now the character doesn't stop moving after I start.